# Laravel error 500 when upload changes to template file

Tags: php, linux, laravel, debian, composer-php

I build laravel project on my remote server, everything works ok but when i saved any changes for example on `resources/views/welcome.blade.php` i cant get in to this default route, browser tells me it is `HTTP ERROR 500`.

And it is same with all files that i changed on server. If i typed `php artisan serve --host 0.0.0.0` in console and go to `192.168.1.4:8000/` every thing works again until again i will saves something new...

I have this issue on fresh laravel project without any changes.
My file permisions:

```
drwxr-sr-x 13 kuchar www-data   4096 Oct 25 09:11 ./
drwxr-sr-x  3 kuchar www-data   4096 Oct 25 08:27 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 kuchar www-data    542 Oct 25 08:30 .env
-rw-r--r--  1 kuchar www-data    491 Oct 25 08:27 .env.example
drwxr-sr-x  8 kuchar www-data   4096 Oct 25 09:13 .git/
-rw-r--r--  1 kuchar www-data     61 Oct 25 08:27 .gitattributes
-rw-r--r--  1 kuchar www-data     95 Oct 25 08:27 .gitignore
drwxr-sr-x  6 kuchar www-data   4096 Oct 25 08:27 app/
-rw-r--r--  1 kuchar www-data   1646 Oct 25 08:27 artisan
drwxr-sr-x  3 kuchar www-data   4096 Oct 25 08:27 bootstrap/
-rw-r--r--  1 kuchar www-data   1283 Oct 25 08:27 composer.json
-rw-r--r--  1 kuchar www-data 124085 Oct 25 08:27 composer.lock
drwxr-sr-x  2 kuchar www-data   4096 Oct 25 08:27 config/
drwxr-sr-x  5 kuchar www-data   4096 Oct 25 08:27 database/
-rw-r--r--  1 kuchar www-data    560 Oct 25 08:27 gulpfile.js
-rw-r--r--  1 kuchar www-data    402 Oct 25 08:27 package.json
-rw-r--r--  1 kuchar www-data    930 Oct 25 08:27 phpunit.xml
drwxr-sr-x  4 kuchar www-data   4096 Oct 25 08:27 public/
-rw-r--r--  1 kuchar www-data   1918 Oct 25 08:27 readme.md
drwxr-sr-x  5 kuchar www-data   4096 Oct 25 08:27 resources/
drwxr-sr-x  2 kuchar www-data   4096 Oct 25 08:27 routes/
-rw-r--r--  1 kuchar www-data    563 Oct 25 08:27 server.php
drwxr-sr-x  5 kuchar www-data   4096 Oct 25 08:27 storage/
drwxr-sr-x  2 kuchar www-data   4096 Oct 25 08:27 tests/
drwxr-sr-x 31 kuchar www-data   4096 Oct 25 08:29 vendor/
-rw-r--r--  1 kuchar www-data 147055 Oct 25 08:27 yarn.lock
```

and virtualhost settings:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName laravel-project.domain
        DocumentRoot "/laravel-project/public"

        <Directory "/laravel-project/public">
                AllowOverride all
        </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

To this project i go with domain `laravel-project.domain` through apache, `artisan serve` use only when error 500 apper

Edit>
Also i try to type command like:

```
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan route:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
```

Nothing works :( only `php artisan serve`

Comment: `drwxr-sr-x` means `755`. Every file on my apache got `644` and folder `755`.

Comment: It's easier to check the error log for whatever server you're using tbh.

Comment: `laravel.log` is clear same in apache logs... :(

Comment: That's odd to say the least, there should be at least some errors in the apache log. For the heck of it, could you run `find <path to files> -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;` and `find <path to files> -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`. This will set the permissions properly for all files and folders.

Comment: yeah ive done this before, thats why all files have `644` and folders `755`

Comment: Fair enough. So if I understand this correctly it stop working as soon as you make ANY change to any template file and save it, correct?

Comment: thats right, and its will work again when i type `artisan serve` and go to this template with localhost not VirtualHost

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/126603/discussion-between-andrew-and-kuchar).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets focus on errors first since they're more important:

1. PHP doesn't have logging errors enabled

   - Make sure that `error_logging` in `php.ini` is enabled.
2. Apache can't read/write its own error log. Which is odd but still, make sure that the permissions are all ok.

   - If you have more than 1 version of php installed do `which php` and make sure that the `PATH` and other such things are ok.

---

Laravel also has some folders that it will whine about if they don't have permissions, namely `storage/*`.

Make sure that apache has permissions to read/write anything that is in that folder.

And also make sure that the owner group for those files is apache.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thats right, i need change owner of folder 'storage' and also his files to www-data:www-data. Thanks this command solved my issue 'sudo chown -R www-data:www-data storage'